# Having trouble with yes and no loops

Tags: c++, loops

So in my computer science class we got to make a lunar lander game. At the very end of the code we are supposed to ask if the user wants to run the game again, while Ive established a yes and no loop, it still doesnt work. It lets me type 'Y' and 'N' but it just breaks right after words.

```
  // Include Section
  #include <iostream>
  #include <cstdlib>
  #include <iomanip>
  using namespace std;

  // Main Program
  int main( )
  {
   // Variable Declarations
   double E;            // Engine output
   double V;            // Velocity output
   double A;            // Altitude output
   double T;            // Time output
   double F;            // Fuel consumption
   double Th;           // Thrust
   double x;            // The variable output the user puts in
   double G;            // The gravity of the moon
   double Acceleration;// The acceleration found between the force and the    
   gravity
   double M;            // Total Mass of the lander
   double Force;        // The force opposing the lunar gravity
   double W;            // Weight 
   double Thrust;       // The initial thrust value
   char Ans;

   A=2300;
   V=0;
   T =0;
   F=300;
   G=-1.62;
   Thrust=43900;
   M= 6831;


// Output Identification
system("CLS");

cout << "Welcome to the Lunar Lander simulation!" << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << "You are in command of the Lunar Lander on its final approach to the moon's surface."
    " You need to control the thrust to the main decent engine."
    " You will adjust it each second by typing in the percent thurst that you would like for the next second."
    " Your goal is to end land the spacecraft at a velocity of less than 1 meter/second."
    <<endl;
cout << endl;
cout << "GOODLUCK!"<<endl;
cout << endl;
cout << setw(8) << "Sec" << setw(10) << "Alt" << setw(10) << "Speed" << setw(8) << "Fuel" << endl;

while(F > 0)
{
    if(A > 0)
    {
        cout << setw(8) << T << setw(10) << A << setw(10) << V 
            << setw(8) << F << setw(14) << "     Enter percent burn (0-100):";
        cin >> x;
        if( x < 0|x > 100)
        {
            cout << "Please pick a valid percentage."<< endl;
        }
        else
        {
            T++;
            x=x/100;
            Th= x*Thrust;
            E= 13.6*x;
            F= F-E;
            M =M-E;
            W=M*G;
            Force=Th+W;
            Acceleration=Force/M;
            V=V+Acceleration*1;
            A=A+V*1-.5*Acceleration*1;
        }
    }
    else
    { 
        if(V <= -1 & V >=-3)
        {
            cout << "Congratulations!" << endl;
            cout << "Would you like to run the simulation again? <Y/N>"<<endl;
            cin >> Ans;
            if(Ans == 'Y'|| Ans == 'y')
                return 0;
            else
                break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Game Over" <<endl;
            cout<< "Would you like to run the simulation again? <Y/N>"<<endl;
            cin >> Ans;
            if(Ans == 'Y'||Ans == 'y')
                return 0;
            else
                break;
        }
    }
    if(F<=0)
    {
    cout<< "Would you like to run the simulation again? <Y/N>"<<endl;
    cin >> Ans;
        if(Ans == 'Y'|| Ans=='y')
            return 0;
        else
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: May I suggest you name your variables with more descriptive names.  Naming your variables `F`, `A`, etc. makes a program much harder to read and follow.

Comment: `return` called in `main()` terminates the program. `break` breaks the enclosing loop and in this case...terminates the program. Neither case changes the value of `F`, so the loop will terminate at the next iteration anyway.

Comment: so return is the main issue I see it?, how do I get loop to go without it returning to a specific line?

Comment: use continue; or just leave do nothing

Comment: I'm assuming when you want to run the game again, to loop back before the line `system("CLS")` - add another while loop starting before this line that checks if `Ans == 'Y' || Ans == 'y'` - initialize `Ans` as "Y" so it goes through the first time.

Comment: Honestly, you should change the structure of your code.  You are repeating the "Would you like to run..." code in several places.  One thing is learn that there are things called `functions` -- the `main` function should be broken down into simple functions, and not one giant blob of code.

Comment: You also are using the wrong operators in your `if` statements: `(x < 0 | x > 100 )` is wrong.  It should be `||`, not `|`.

Comment: Were learning about functions right now actually! so while this probably isnt the best looking code, its what I have to turn in until I get further into the course. Im still having trouble as it gave me several errors when I tried to create a while statement before the statement that checks if Ans==Y, its hard to tell what the while statement should be doing, while(?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cout<< "Would you like to run the simulation again? <Y/N>"<<endl;
cin >> Ans;
    if(Ans == 'Y'|| Ans=='y')
        return 0;
    else
        break;
```

Return 0 does not help your code run the loop again.
I guess you can modify your code in form of

```
while(1){
cout<< "Would you like to run the simulation again? <Y/N>"<<endl;
cin >> Ans;
if(Ans == 'N'||Ans == 'n')break;
}
```

Hope that might help you.

Comment: this def helps, but its not showing anything after it, if the person hits Y it doesnt re run the program just gives a large spot afterwards. Thanks for your help!

Comment: By the way, you should really try to use "switch( )" in your code. It would make your coding style much neat

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more elegant solution.

```
std::string line;
do {
  // code to be repeated upon "Y"
} while (std::getline(std::cin, line) && line == "Y");
```

Comment: Im not quite sure what string line does? I havent been taught about strings yet, thats what we learn at the end of the semester.

Comment: It declares line to be a string, which is a type (class) defined by the standard library for holding a consecutive list of characters. You can think about it like a nice char array if you've been taught about that.

Comment: arrays? we're just starting to learn about functions like void and function prototypes. Im sure IM making this more complicated than this truly is, but im messing around with bool expressions and stuff that Im not very familiar with at all. While IM learning a lot I also feel like IM screwing up my code a lot haha

Comment: Nothing truly required the string, but if your user decided to respond with more than one character and you don't read the whole line like I did, funky things would happen. For now feel free to use it verbatim and discover how it works later in your course. =)

Answer (score 0):

After fixing the obvious errors of using `|` instead of `||` and other issues is this:

It would help if you introduced some simple `bool` variables to determine whether the loops in your code should continue or not.

For example:

```
 bool inputOk;
 do
 {
    inputOk = true;
    cout << setw(8) << TimeOutput << setw(10) << Altitude << setw(10) << V
          << setw(8) << F << setw(14) << "     Enter percent burn (0-100):";
    cin >> x;
    if (x < 0 || x > 100)
    {
        cout << "Please pick a valid percentage." << endl;
        inputOk = false;
    }
}  while (!inputOk);
```

You now don't need to have an `else` after this code, as this will only leave the loop until the input is ok.

Given this, you should use the same technique as above for your entire loop, where you are asking to run another simulation:

```
bool runLoop;  // instead of while (F > 0)
do 
{
   runLoop = true;
   //.. your other code
   //...
   cout << "Would you like to run the simulation again? <Y/N>" << endl;
   cin >> Ans;
   if (Ans != 'Y' && Ans != 'y')
        runLoop = false;
//...
} while (runloop);
```

Very simple.  You just keep running the loop until the user doesn't want to run any more simulations.  You accomplish this by writing a do-while, and testing for the `runLoop` status.  If the user decides to quit, the `runLoop` is set to false, thus the loop terminates.